# Ошибка Django Model class articles.models.Article doesn't declare

Tags: django

начал изучать Django и выскочила вот такая ошибка 
"RuntimeError: Model class articles.models.Article doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS."
Хотя articles прописан в INSTALLED_APPS :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'articles.apps.ArticlesConfig',
]
```

Файл models.py

```
    import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Article(models.Model):
    article_title = models.CharField('Названия статьи', max_length = 100)
    article_text = models.TextField('Текст статьи')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Дата публикации')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.article_title

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= (timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Статья'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Статьи'


class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    author_name = models.CharField('Имя автора', max_length = 20)
    comment_text = models.CharField('Текст коммента', max_length = 200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Комментарий'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Комментарии'
```

Файл Settings

```
import os, sys

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps'))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '#d$ovp!2_5bm@bp6x3aukkq+4^_517a80@&b3)of*nh95#vry('

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'articles.apps.ArticlesConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myfirst.urls'


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myfirst.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Покажите ваш ArticlesConfig

Comment: Вам нужен файл models.py?

Comment: Нет, нам нужен ваш ArticlesConfig

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая же ситуация я перенес папку с приложениям в папку проекта и заработоло не знаю с чем связано